# In JPA, how much does it matter when a transaction begins?

Tags: jpa, transactions

A JPA transaction commit is supposed to save all changes to the entities associated with the persistence context that have happened so far. So it matters a lot where the `commit()` is located. How much does it matter where the `begin()` is? Consider the following two scenarios, both of which create entity `x`, associate `x` with a persistence context, and later modify that entity and [purport to] save the changes to `x` to the database:

```
// Scenario A
EntityManager em = ...
MyEntity x = new MyEntity();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(x);
em.getTransaction().commit();
// ... do some stuff ...    
x.a = val1;
x.setB(val2);
em.getTransaction().begin(); // *a "late begin"*
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

vs.

```
// Scenario B
EntityManager em = ...
MyEntity x = new MyEntity();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(x);
em.getTransaction().commit();
// ... do some stuff ...    
em.getTransaction().begin(); //  *an "early begin"*
x.a = val1;
x.setB(val2);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

In both scenarios, object `x` belongs to the persistence context of `EntityManager em`.
Isn't it the case that, in both scenarios, the second `commit` will save all changes to `em`'s context, including those to `x.a` and `x.b`, that have happened since the first commit?

In this case, what is the functional difference between the two scenarios?

Let's assume we use no Spring, Java Beans, and other advanced technologies; just the Java Persistence API and the OpenJPA implementation.

Comment: P.S. Let's assume that flushMode=AUTO, so no explicit flush() is ever needed.

Comment: As long as you're not issuing queries (directly or otherwise) - not much of a difference. Issuing queries might have different semantics in the two cases, because depending on the transaction isolation level, locks may be acquired on selected data in the 'early' case. And, of course, some operations like trying to acquire a pessimistic lock, will fail outside of a transaction altogether